# Is it worth using bit shifting to store multiple small data members in a single byte?

Tags: c++

In C++, the smallest size of any object or primitive data type is 1 byte.  However, I frequently use enumerated types with only a few possible values.  It recently came up in a project for one of my courses  that I had to store many structs containing two different, small enumerated types.  So, of course, I made the underlying type of the enumerated types unsigned chars, and made the structs each 2 bytes.

However, since each enumerated type had far fewer than 16 possible values, I realized I could use bit shifting to store them in only 1 byte.

Here is something like what I'm talking about:

```
enum utensil : unsigned char {fork, spoon, spork};
enum dish : unsigned char {plate, bowl, box};
enum food : unsigned char {soup, salad, entree};
enum dessert: unsigned char {cake, ice_cream, fudge};

/* A class containing one of each of the four enums 
above, but only taking up 1 byte of memory */

class TakeOut{
  private:
    unsigned char data = 0;

    void clear_utensil(){
       data = data & 0b00111111;
    }
    void clear_dish(){
       data = data & 0b11001111;
    }
    void clear_food(){
       data = data & 0b11110011;
    }
    void clear_dessert(){
       data = data & 0b11111100;
    }
  public:
    utensil get_utensil() const{
       return utensil((data & 11000000) >> 6);
    }
    dish get_dish() const{
       return dish((data & 00110000) >> 4);
    }
    food get_food() const{
       return food((data & 00001100) >> 2);
    }
    dessert get_dessert() const{
       return dessert(data & 00000011);
    }
    void set_utensil(utensil in){
       clear_utensil();
       data = data | ((unsigned char)(in) << 6);
    }
    void set_dish(dish in){
       clear_dish();
       data = data | ((unsigned char)(in) << 4);
    }
    void set_food(utensil in){
       clear_food();
       data = data | ((unsigned char)(in) << 2);
    }
    void set_dessert(utensil in){
       clear_dessert();
       data = data | (unsigned char)(in);
    }
};
```

Should I avoid doing this on 'real' projects if the opportunity ever presents itself again?  It's complicated, sure, but if I have to store a lot of TakeOut objects, maybe it's worth it for a small sacrifice of time in accessing data members.

Comment: If you are working in an embedded system, it might make sense as they are often space constrained.  If you're using desktop computers, I wouldn't do this.  Ram and mass storage is cheap and plentiful and the space saving isn't worth the maintainability hassle.

Comment: @NathanOliver you can use bitfields and avoid almost all maintainability hassle (see my answer). The bigger issue is that it severely hurts performance.

Comment: If you're literally creating millions of such objects, it can make a difference, sure. In all other situations, you're just complicating the code, and introducing the possibility of bugs (consider further maintenance down the line).

Answer (score 5):

You do not need to use bit-shifting for this, you might use bit-fields in structures. This gives you the same functionality with significantly less typing (which means less maintenance, less error prone and more fun!):

```
enum utensil_t : unsigned char {fork, spoon, spork};
enum dish_t : unsigned char {plate, bowl, box};
enum food_t : unsigned char {soup, salad, entree};
enum dessert_t: unsigned char {cake, ice_cream, fudge};

struct TakeOut {
    utensil_t utensil : 2;
    dish_t dish : 2;
    food_t food : 2;
    dessert_t dessert : 2;
};
```

However, please note that when you are doing this, you are trading performance for size, and most likely you do not want this trade. Unless you are dealing with a lot of those in a very constrained environment.

**Language-lawyer note**: Technically, C++ compiler is not **required** to pack bitfields, as their layout is implementation defined. Practically I do not think there is any implementation in practice which doesn't pack bitfields. You can easily protect yourself from insane implementation with:

```
static_assert(sizeof(TakeOut) == 1, "Sanity, please!");
```

Comment: Using bitfields doesn’t necessarily save space. The layout of bitfields is implementation-defined.

Comment: @PeteBecker and implementation I use define it in a sane way (i.e. they do pack them). I added this detail for completeness.